# Template variable in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have to add a Page's variable into a ItemTemplate but dont know how.

For example:

```
<rad:RadMenuItem ID="f" runat="server" Text="Products">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="pitem"><%= MyText %></div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</rad:RadMenuItem>
```

The MyText variable does exist in the context and has value but the text does not show up

Another question:
How can I add MyText to the ASP.NET page like the following?

```
<asp:Button Text="<%=MyText%>" .../>
```

I dont want to edit the code like btn.Text=MyText, just want to do that on the .aspx file as required.

Comment: I have the answer for the first question: using <%# MyText %>

Comment: How about the second one?, please help

Answer (score 0):

Answers to second question. (Btw, you should only ask one question at a time here on Stack Overflow.)

You could use

```
<asp:Button Text="<%# MyText %>" />
```

if you call DataBind() in you code behind.

```
public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

If the databind is expensive, I believe you could use this code, so that you only call it once, and then save the values in the ViewState.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: With the code <asp:Button Text="<%=MyText%>" .../>, the button text shows extactly "<%=MyText%>", not the text I want.

Comment: It's `<%# MyText %>` - not `<%= MyText %>`. But changing the equals to hash will probably not change anything. Hrm.. :-/